# Unramified primes inside $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$

Tags: finite-fields, function-fields

I have some questions about the following statement:

> Let $P \subset \mathbb{F}_q(t)$ be a prime, with $q=p^e$ for a prime number $p$ and $f$ a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients inside $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$.
>   Let $K$ be the residue field of $P$ and $\overline{f}$ the image of $f$ over $K$.
>
> If $\overline{f}$ is squarefree over $K$, $P$ is unramified over $\mathbb{F}_q(t)[X] / f$.

Until now I have seen ramified/unramified primes only in the case of number fields, so perhaps I am missing something.
I would appreciate it if someone could check my thoughts about this statement.

1. $P \in \mathbb{F}_q[t]$
2. $K = \mathbb{F}_q[t] / (p) = \mathbb{F}_{q^k}[t]$ for some $k$.

Also I would appreciate a definition of ramification/unramified in this context. Now I can not see, why this statement should be true.

Comment: The second statement is a bit unclear to me. $K$ is a field, but $\Bbb{F}_{q^k}[t]$ most certainly is not. Did you mean to leave out the $[t]$-part?

Comment: Anyway, in case you haven't already done so, I recommend that you also familiarize yourself with the geometric point of view here. You can think of $f$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb{F}_q[t,X]$ (clear the eventual denominators), and that defines a curve in the $(t,X)$-plane (and in its projective closure to include the points at infinity, or the primes lying above $P=(1/t)$. You need to go to a smooth model to get bijective correspondence between the primes of the function field and the points on the projective curve, but that can wait.

Comment: Oh, you are right. With $[t]$ it is not a field. So should I actually think about $P$ as a place and $K$ as valuation ring modulo this place? But why should be $\mathcal{O}_P / P = \mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: And about the geometric point of view:
Let's say that I take a look at $X^8+t+1 \in \mathbb{F}_7$. Then I can rewrite X = (t+1)^(1/8), which I can draw in the $(t, X)$-plane. How should this help?

Comment: We have $\mathcal{O}_P/P=\Bbb{F}_q$ only when $P$ is a degree $1$ place. Usually it is an extension field.

Comment: With $F(t,X):=X^8+t+1$ you get ramification at the place corresponding to the irreducible polynomial $t+1$. Or, if you prefer, at the point $Q=(t,X)=(-1,0)$. At that point only $X$ is a local parameter, and the valuation $\nu_Q(t+1)=8$. So we get $e=8$. Calculus shows the same thing. The curve $t+1=-X^8$ has a vertical tangent at $(t,X)=(-1,0)$. The implicit function theorem says the same thing as $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial X}(Q)=0.$$ IIRC the place $t=\infty$ also ramifies in $\Bbb{F}_q(t,X)$.

Comment: On the other hand, the place $t=-2$ is unramified in $\Bbb{F}_q(t,X)$. Now
$$F(-2,X)=X^8-1=(X-1)(X+1)(X^2+1)(X^4+1)\equiv(X-1)(X+1)(X^2+1)(X^2+3X+1)(X^2-3X+1)$$ so there are five distinct places above $t=-2$. Two of degree one, and three of degree two.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. I would like to describe what I got so far, from what you have written.

What do I know about the $K$ in the statement of the question:
Because $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$ is a rational function field $K = \mathcal{O}_P / P = \mathbb{F}_q[t] / p(t)$, with $P = P_{p(t)}$.
Is it possbile to specifiy $K$ even more?

Comment: I see that $F(-1, 0) = 0$ but why does this correspnd to $t+1$?
To every place $P$ I can associate a discrete valuation function. 
Esspecially for $z \neq 0$ I have $\mathit{v}_P(z) = n$ with $z = s^n*u$ for $u \in \mathcal{O}_P^{*}$ and $s\mathcal{O} = P$. So in the example you get that $n=8$, so you can follow that $e=8$, but how do you get that $n=8$. What is your $s$ and $u$?

Comment: I understand your example with $t = -2$
You take the irreducible polynomial $t + 2$ and look at $t + 2 = 0$, hence you get $F(-2,0)$ [Ahhhhh, thats how t+1 and F(-1, 0) correspond!]
Then you factor into irreducibles and take a look at the degree of these. This degree correspond to the degree of the places, by what I have written two comments above about $K$. The place is unramified, because we have every irreducible polynomial only with a power of 1.

Comment: One last (perhaps very basic) question: So actually I can associate my Places $P$ to zeros of the polynomial $f$?
May I think about places as "normal zeros"?

Comment: Yes. WHen taking the quotient ring by moding out the ideal $t-a$ you effectively set $t=a$. When you mod out a higher degree irreducible polynomial you get a higher degree place. Geometrically you then look at points whose coordinates are Galois conjugates of each other - all lumped together to form a single place.

Comment: On the curve $X^8+t+1=0$ we have the ring $\mathcal{O}_Q$ of rational functions defined at $(t,X)=(-1,0)$. It has a maximal ideal $m_Q$ of those functions that vanish at $Q$. That ideal is generated by $t+1$ and $X$. An actually we see that $X$ alone suffices. Basicall because the equation $X^8=-(t+1)$ tells us how to write $t+1$ as a multiple of $X$. So $m_Q=\langle X\rangle$. The general theory says that $\mathcal{O}_Q$ is a DVR, and as a generator of the maximal ideal we can use $X$ to define the valuation. We have $t+1=(-1)\cdot X^8$. So here $u=-1$ and $s=X$.

Comment: At tthe point $R$ with coordinates $t=-2,X=1$ we use the equation $X^8+t+1=0$ in the forms
$$t+2=-(X^8-1)=-(X^7+X^6+\cdots+X+1)(X-1)$$
and
$$(X-1)=-\frac{t+2}{X^7+X^6+\cdots+X+1}$$ to see that either $t+2$ or $X-1$ **alone** generates the ideal $m_R$. So either $t+2$ or $X-1$ can serve in the role of the local parameter $s$ in defining the valuation. Anyway, because $t+2$ generates the maximal ideal it follows that $\nu_R(t+2)=1$ meaning that the place $R$ lying above $P=t+2$ is unramified.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for explanations (and the many examples, that helped a lot!). 
I think I got it now!